# Android debugging: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, debugging, gesture

I received this stack trace today and am having a problem finding the problem.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:792)
at android.widget.ScrollView.onTouchEvent(ScrollView.java:509)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3766)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1720)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1117)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1704)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It looks to me that the problem is in this piece of code. But it's so small and simple, I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas?

```
@Override 
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
       this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me); 
     }

     public void onSwipe(int direction) {
      String str = "";

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : wv.loadUrl("javascript:slideRight()");
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  wv.loadUrl("javascript:slideLeft()");
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  wv.loadUrl("javascript:slideDown()");
                                                     break;
      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    wv.loadUrl("javascript:slideUp()");
                                                     break;

      } 

     }
```

Could it just be a bug that is native to android?

Edit:
I'm using this for this.detector.onTouchEvent(me); to listen for swipe events.

```
public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

     public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
     public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
     public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
     public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

     public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
     public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
     public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

     private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
     private int swipe_Min_Distance = 200;
     private int swipe_Max_Distance = 800;
     private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

     private int mode = MODE_DYNAMIC;
     private boolean running = true;
     private boolean tapIndicator = false;

     private Activity context;
     private GestureDetector detector;
     private SimpleGestureListener listener;


     public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

      this.context = context;
      this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
      this.listener = sgl; 
     }

     public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

       if(!this.running)
      return;  

       boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event); 

       if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
       else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

         if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE) 
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
         else if (result)
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL); 
         else if(this.tapIndicator){
          event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
          this.tapIndicator = false;
         }

       }
       //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
     }

     public void setMode(int m){
      this.mode = m;
     }

     public int getMode(){
      return this.mode;
     }

     public void setEnabled(boolean status){
      this.running = status;
     }

     public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
     }


     @Override
     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
       float velocityY) {

      final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
      final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

      if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
       return false;

      velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
      velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
            boolean result = false;

      if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
       if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
       else
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

       result = true;
      }
      else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
       if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up 
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
       else
        this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

       result = true;
      }

       return result;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      this.tapIndicator = true;
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
      this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg0) {

      if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an       
         arg0.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.                                    
         this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg0);  
      }   

      return false;
     }


        static interface SimpleGestureListener{
         void onSwipe(int direction);
         void onDoubleTap();
     }

    }
```

Comment: Certainly not. You're probably calling `getY()` with an invalid parameter. What's the code for `detector.onTouchEvent()`? What's the package name of your app?

Comment: Like EboMike is saying, notice the exception is thrown from getY() from onTouchEvent().  Post the relevant code for detector

Answer (score 3):

i got this error too from android market.

it seems like a platform thing, or a bug trickling down from some parent:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10238#c6

and a patch on the way:
https://review.source.android.com/#change,21318